# Carrierwave multiple picture upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using a carrierwave gem 0.10.0 to upload 1 picture to the model. Now I want to be able to attach several pictures so I followed the steps from documentation one of which was to change `gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'` to `gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'`.

After that I'm getting such error `uninitialized constant CarrierWave::MimeTypes`. Any ideas on what's going on?

P.S. If I delete include CarrierWave::MimeTypes in file_uploader.rb several pictures uploading works just fine

Comment: Checking the carrierwave closed issues, they deprecated it back in January.

Comment: What do you have in your uploader? Please show.

Comment: Do you mean in file_uploader?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the closed issue?

Comment: It was a merge apparently and is closed. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1813

Comment: So I don't have to worry about MimeTypes any more? Just comment that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used to do this manually like so:

```
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'

class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  process :set_content_type
end
```

Now you just remove the mime types part.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#setting-the-content-type